# Designing an Enum

Tags: java, enums

I am writing a code in which i need filesize and filesize unit. Lets say if someone is calling my function he would call it
`myfun (3, MB)`

Which means the expected file size would be 3 MB. I am thinking to put this "file unit" in an enum

```
public enum SizeUnit {BYTE, KILOBYTE, MEGABYTE, GIGABYTE}
```

Now the problem is converting the the given size into bytes. Of course i can do simple math, but i want something more genering. so lets say if somene has called me function like

`myfun (3, MEGABYTE)`
in my code i want simply `3 * MEGABYTE` to convert it into `BYTE` unit.

I am not sure if this is possible ... I am just thinking about one possibility. There could be a method in enum, which takes the its unit and do the calculation? (i don't want to do the trivial one, there should be something generic enough).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html - They kinda cover exactly that in the the tutorial

Comment: Do you want kilo byte to be 1000 bytes (as it is for disk space) or 1024 which it is for memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public enum SizeUnit
{
  BYTE(1),
  KILOBYTE(1024),
  ...;

  private final int bytes; 
  private SizeUnit(final int bytes) { this.bytes = bytes; }
  public int getByteCount() { return this.bytes; }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
3 * KILOBYTE.getByteCount();
```

or even define a method called `getBytes` which passes a number.  So `KILOBYTE.getBytes(3)`.

Comment: This is not what i was asking for. I know that i can do this thing. Perhaps i am not clear enough in my question. but thanks for down-votes!

Answer (score 0):

TimeUnit does something similar it has a method which converts to a base unit, in your case bytes.

What I do is use

```
 3 * 1024 // as 3 KB
 3 * 1024 * 1024 // as 3 MB
```

This makes it clear I done mean

```
 3 * 1000 // as 3 KB of disk space.
 3 * 1000 * 1000 // as 3 MB of disk space.
```